# Have PDF hyperlinks open in a new window in InDesign CS5

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I'm created an InDesign file using CS5. Where do I find the option to have my hyperlinks open in a new browser window? When I create the PDF from InDesign and post the PDF on my web site the links work, but open in the same browser window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't tell your PDF how to handle links from InDesign.

From the [Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3141604):

> If you want your hyperlink to an open an URL in another browser window, I don't think there is anyway to specify this directly in
>   InDesign. However in Acrobat, instead of using an open web link
>   action, you can use the following "Run a JavaScript" action to do
>   this:
>
> ```
> app.launchURL("http://www.intendedsitehere.com/",true);
> ```

To add the Javascript, go to the Button's `Properties > Actions Tab > Select Action: Run a Javascript` and choose Add. You can write the previous code in the Javascript Editor.

UPDATE: Apparently the JS doesn't work with Acrobat X unless the user has some security settings modified. It also seems to have some issues in Chrome. So most people won't be able to see it. [According to this thread](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1242465) in the same forum, as of today there is no way to guarantee a hyperlink will open in a new tab using InDesign and/or Acrobat.

Comment: Ok, if I use that in Acrobat. Should I even add the hyperlink in InDesign or just add the hyperlink in Acrobat?

Comment: My guess is you don't need to add it in InDesign, and it might get overwritten anyway. But I've just edited the question with more information, apparently the JS is not 100% reliable, as it doesn't work in Chrome :/